# Lagrange interpolating polynomials generalized

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analyticity

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be arbitrary but subject to the following conditions:

$(i)$: $S$ is countably infinite

$(ii): \inf\{||\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}|| : \textbf{x},\textbf{y} \in S \  \text{and} \ \textbf{x} \neq \textbf{y}\} > 0$

$(iii)$: If $\textbf{p} = (x_1, y_1)$ and $\textbf{q} = (x_1, y_2)$ are both elements in $S$, then $y_1 = y_2$.

$(iv)$: The $x$ coordinates are discrete in $\mathbb{R}$. (credit to Daniel Fischer in the comments for this)

Roughly speaking, these are just points in the $xy$ plane which pass the vertical line test and are 'well behaved' in the sense that they're all far apart from each other. It is possible that the second condition is strictly unnecessary for my question.

> For any such set, can we construct a $f \in C^{\omega}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $S \subset \{(x, f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$? In other words, is there an analytic function which passes through all of the points of $S$?

This is sort of a generalization of the Langrange interpolating polynomials, except with them the set $S$ is strictly finite.  In this case, polynomials don't always work. For example, if all but one member of $S$ lies on the line $y=0$, then the function must have an infinite number of zeroes but not be the zero polynomial, hence it can't be a polynomial.

Comment: Consider $S = \{ (1/n, n) : n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\}$. You need the set of $x$-coordinates discrete, if you have that, then you can construct an interpolating (real-)analytic $f$.

Comment: In your example $S$, are you sure that the $x$ coordinates are _not_ discrete? I think the infimum of the distance between the $x$ coordinates should be positive.

Comment: I meant "discrete in $\mathbb{R}$" (i.e. having no accumulation point in $\mathbb{R}$), not "discrete in the subspace topology". Unclear terminology for the win. Having that, you can do more, you can prescribe the Taylor expansion to order $m_n$ at $x_n$ too. That interpolation theorem is typically proved in complex analysis (e.g. in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* it's theorem 15.13).